# Netlogo Distance and Forward Commands

Tags: distance, netlogo, agent, forward, turtle-graphics

I'm building a model to simulate an aircraft flying through contested airspace.

My model is a 400x50 tile zone with each tile intended to represent a mile. I'm having two issues right now.

1) In order to move the aircraft (turtle 0), I use the following code:

```
 to go
 ask turtle 0
 [forward speed]
 check-engagement
 check-state
 end
```

where speed is defined on a slider. However, this is not working as intended. When the speed is set to 1, the turtle appears to jump forward by 5 tiles. Conversely, when the speed is set to 2 it jumps forward 10. I can obviously just divide by 5, but I'm not sure why this is.

Next, I check the distance to other Red Force turtles using this code:

```
to check-engagement
 ask redfor
  [ 
   let d DISTANCE turtle 0
   ifelse d <= range 
   [detect]
   [stop] 
  ]  
 end
```

where range is again set on a slider. However, as I move forwards it is an all or nothing scenario. As soon as the first red unit detects the aircraft it appears that all red units detect it, even though I have no links. Additionally, it appears that all red units + 1 detect it (if 4 units on map, 5 units detect it).

I don't understand why this would be because I'm asking redfor about the aircraft (turtle 0).

Comment: Is the `go` a forever button? If so, I think what is happening is not that it is ALWAYS 5 and +1. I think it is repeating the loop and different red units are detecting at different ticks.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the code you've posted, so I think the problem is somewhere else, in something you haven't shown us or described.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Troubleshooting some I found that if I changed the "go" button from 'Turtle' to 'Observer' it solved the problem...now I just have to figure out how to "ask" the turtle something while still in "go" as an observer.